# How two run mulitiple Sql Server 2008 DB on one MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I have one application using MVC3 w/ Razor that has been working perfectly working with one database. I am now encountering this error when trying to access the second database:

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

I assumed adding another DbContext class to the project would be the same process I used to add the first pre-created database, so I added the second connection string to the web.config just like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DbContext1" connectionString="Data Source=db1.server.com;Initial Catalog=dbName1;User Id=db1;Password=*&#!$;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="DbContext2" connectionString="Data Source=db2.server.com;Initial Catalog=dbName2;User Id=db2;Password=*&#!$;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I then added the second DbContext class to the application:

```
public class DbContext1 : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Table1> Object1 { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Table2> Object2 { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Table3> Object3 { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Table4> Object4 { get; set; }
}


public class DbContext2 : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Table1> Object5 { get; set; }
}
```

The problem appears when I try to access the second database. The first database is still working like a charm, but for some reason, the second database appears to be trying to create a new database rather than read the existing database at the end of the connection string. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try explicitly selecting the context, either in the constructor of your classes:

```
public class DbContext1 : DbContext
{
    public DbContext1() : base("DbContext1")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Table1> Object1 { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Table2> Object2 { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Table3> Object3 { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Table4> Object4 { get; set; }
}


public class DbContext2 : DbContext
{
    public DbContext2() : base("DbContext2")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Table1> Object5 { get; set; }
}
```

Or, overloading the constructor to accept a connection string, and calling it in your code:

```
public class DbContext2 : DbContext
{
    public DbContext2(string connectionString)  : base (connectionString)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Table1> Object5 { get; set; }
}
```

and then when you create a new context:

```
var context = new DbContext2("DbContext2");
```

Comment: I've just tried both and still no go. EF is still attempting to create the database.

Comment: To confirm, the DbContext2 connection string database matches your DbContext2 Model exactly?

Comment: I did. After getting frustrated, I went back and deleted the controller, views, second DbContext, and re-ran the script to delete and build the database, and then went back through the process of generating the controller and views; now everything is working. I have no idea why, but the DBs are hosted by godaddy, so no telling after the day we've had. I ran the script to create the database this morning and added some test data to the DB and didn't have a chance to really get back in and work with them until a few hours ago when GD got up and running again, to see that they weren't hooking up.

Comment: I've been researching this for a few hours, so I know that your answer is the typical solution to my question. I'm going to mark yours as the correct answer and chalk up my scenario as a fluke. Thanks for your time and efforts.